# Java Joda time isAfter date solution

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to compare two dates.
If the current date time is greater or after the 
specific date , then it will return 'True'.

So far I have tried this.

```
String deadline = "25/11/2017 11:00:00";
DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Dhaka");
DateTime dhakaTime = utc.toDateTime(timeZone);
//Dead Line Time
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime deadlineTime = format.parseDateTime(deadline.trim());
//Comapare
return deadlineTime.isAfter(dhakaTime.plusDays(2));
```

As today is 23 and dhakaTime.plusDays(2) will be 25 so it should return
"true".

But I am getting "false".

Output value :

> dhakaTime.plusDays(2) = 2017-11-25T14:10:27.762+06:00
>   deadlineTime = 2017-11-25T11:00:00.000+06:00

Am i missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Print out the two dates and check their values. You might find the solution there.

Comment: dhakaTime.plusDays(2) = 2017-11-25T14:10:27.762+06:00
 deadlineTime =  2017-11-25T11:00:00.000+06:00

Comment: @MadJavaProgrammer I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives `false` correctly.

You're comparing

```
deadLineTime = 2017-11-25T11:00:00.000+06:00 and 
dhakaTime(+2) =  2017-11-25T14:10:27.762+06:00
```

They both are at same date, but with time, `deadLineTime` is at **11AM** but `dhakaTime(+2)` is at **2PM**. So,

`(Nov 25, 2017 11AM)isAfter(Nov 25, 2017 2PM)` is `false`.

**EDIT: Testcases**

As you mentioned you're testing, The following used different test cases for comparing `deadLine` with `dhakaTime` (+1, and +2 days). I hope this gives you an idea about how this works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String deadline = "25/11/2017 11:00:00";
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Dhaka");
    DateTime dhakaTime = utc.toDateTime(timeZone);
    //Dead Line Time
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime deadlineTime = format.parseDateTime(deadline.trim());

    System.out.println("Deadline : " + deadline);
    System.out.println("Current datetim : " + dhakaTime);
    System.out.println("current datetime + 1 day : " + dhakaTime.plusDays(1));
    System.out.println("current datetime + 2 day : " + dhakaTime.plusDays(2));

    System.out.println("Is deadline after current datetime:" + deadlineTime.isAfter(dhakaTime)); 
    System.out.println("Is deadline after current datetime + 1 day:" + deadlineTime.isAfter(dhakaTime.plusDays(1))); 
    System.out.println("Is deadline after current datetime + 2 day:" + deadlineTime.isAfter(dhakaTime.plusDays(2))); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding 2 days for dhakaTime ?

Comment: I think i need to do this : dhakaTime.isAfter(deadlineTime) right?

Comment: If its for your testing, I think its correct as it is. So, you can add one day for `dhakaTime` and it will return true, until dhakaTime is `27-11-2017 10:59:59`. When you added 2 days, the time already exceeded the deadLine, which should return `false`. And, its working correctly.

Comment: If you do, `dhakaTime.isAfter(deadlineTime)`, it will return `true` only when `dhakaTime` is greater than `deadLine` time. Which means, you're checking only when you've exceeded the deadLineTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method DateTimeFormatter withZone(DateTimeZone zone) and use that to create the DateTime